# Passing an array to table Views in Iphone/Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, tableview

I am trying to pass an array of float data to a table view but didn't manage to get it working. Currently I am just passing an array with text to be displayed, which was based on an example. Ideally I would like to use the result of calculations being put into an array to fill the table view. What would you suggest to accomplish this task?

**Button**

```
-(IBAction) selectDate:(id)sender;
{
    if ( [[[sender titleLabel] text] isEqualToString:@"Set Start Date"])

    {

    startDate = [pickerDate date];
    [startDate retain];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yy"];
    labelStartDate.text = [dateFormat stringFromDate:startDate];
    [dateFormat release];
    //buttonDateStart.enabled = NO;
    }

    if ( [[[sender titleLabel] text] isEqualToString:@"Set End Date"])

    {

        endDate = [pickerDate date];
        [endDate retain];
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yy"];
        labelEndDate.text = [dateFormat stringFromDate:endDate];
```

**Data being used**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {


    NSDictionary *row1 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: 
                          @"MacBook" , @"Name",@"White",@"Color",nil];


    NSDictionary *row2 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          @"MacBook pro",@"Name",@"Silver",@"Color",nil];

    NSDictionary *row3 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          @"iMac",@"Name",@"White",@"Color",nil];

    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: row1,row2,row3, nil];
    self.computers = array;


    [row1 release];
    [row2 release];
    [row3 release];
```

**Table**

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return[self.computers count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
        cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellTableIdentifier = @"CellTableIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellTableIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil){
        CGRect cellFrame = CGRectMake(0,0,300,65);
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame: cellFrame
                        reuseIdentifier:CellTableIdentifier] autorelease];

        //create the 2 rows

        CGRect nameLabelRect = CGRectMake(0,5,70,15);
        UILabel *nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:nameLabelRect];     
        nameLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
        nameLabel.text = @"Date:";
        nameLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
        [cell.contentView addSubview: nameLabel];
        [nameLabel release];        

        CGRect colorLabelRect = CGRectMake(0,26,70,15);
        UILabel *colorLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:colorLabelRect];       
        nameLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
        colorLabel.text = @"Amount:";
        colorLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
        [cell.contentView addSubview: colorLabel];
        [colorLabel release];               

        CGRect nameValueRect = CGRectMake(80,5,200,15);
        UILabel *nameValue = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:nameValueRect];             
        nameValue.tag = kNameValueTag;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:nameValue];
        [nameValue release];

        CGRect colorValueRect = CGRectMake(80,25,200,15);
        UILabel *colorValue = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:colorValueRect];               
        colorValue.tag = kColorValueTag;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:colorValue];
        [colorValue release];           
    }

    //Data source

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSDictionary *rowData = [self.computers objectAtIndex:row];
    UILabel *name = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:kNameValueTag];
    name.text = [rowData objectForKey:@"Name"];

    UILabel *color = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:kColorValueTag];  
    color.text = [rowData objectForKey:@"Color"];
    return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since float values are no real Objective-C objects, you have to pack them in `NSNumber` objects, which you can then put in arrays, dictionaries and the like.

To get a float value in an NSNumber object:

```
float yourFloat;
NSNumber *myNumber = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:yourFloat];
```

The get the value out of the NSNumber:

```
float someFloat = [myNumber floatValue];
```

The same works for `BOOL`, `NSInteger` and various other types (see the docs of `NSNumber`). For non-numeric values, use `NSValue` which allows you to wrap arbitrary non-object values.

Comment: Then convert it to a NSString for display in the table cell using [NSString stringWithFormat:"%f", someFloat];

Answer (score 0):

In your .h file, did you make sure to implement

```
@interface myClass : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

then call

```
[self.tableView setDelegate:self];
```

and

```
[self.tableView setDataSource:self];
```

the controller wont load data unless you specify the delegate and datasource